# Assigning selector output to an array - JQuery

Tags: jquery

```
var arr = $(".producttypeid");
var premiumtypecodes = Array(arr.length);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    premiumtypecodes[i] = arr[i].value;
```

The above code does not seem to work. The intent is to assign the output to an array. Anything that I am missing. 
Why this simple code does not work? Reasoning would be highly appreciated....

Based on the feedback I am adding sample markup and adding details to make my intent unambigous.

```
<input class="producttypeid" type="hidden" value="512">
```

I want to extract the value from all tags using style producttypeid and make an array

Comment: It might be that the selected DOM elements are not form elements and therefore don't have a `value` property. What kind of elements are `.producttypeid`?

Comment: Just a thought: Are you sure that you need conversion? A wrapped set is basically an array, maybe you can use arr directly?

Comment: Adding more data to the question. I just need to capture the value attribute. Here is the sample markup <input class="producttypeid" type="hidden" value="512">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
var arr = $(".producttypeid");
var premiumtypecodes = [];
arr.each(function(index) {
    premiumtypecodes[index] = this.value;
});
```

That assumes all of the matching elements are `input` elements (because of the use of `value`). If some of them may be `textarea` or `select` elements, then change the line inside the iterator function to:

```
    premiumtypecodes[index] = $(this).val();
```

If they're not form fields at all, you'll have to define what you mean by their "value" (e.g., you might use `$(this).text()` to get their text content, or `$(this).html()` to get their markup, or something else entirely).

I'm not immediately seeing any problem with your version other than that you're missing an `i` after `var`:

```
for (var = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
//       ^--- here
```

Other than that, it should have worked, but note that although `Array(arr.length)` works, the usual way to write it is `new Array(arr.length)` (and there's no need to pre-set the length; JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) so you don't get the usual benefit of doing that).

Comment: Fixed the typo in the code.. was trying various combinations on my machine. Forgot to edit correctly for the problem I wanted to describe. Thanks

Comment: @user129206: If the above didn't sort it out, you'll have to create a minimal replicating test case and post it to the question (and ideally also to http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net, but definitely include the code in the question as well).

Comment: I was actually using the literal representation for an array as used by you in your code. var premiumtypecodes = []; Since this did not work I was trying various ways. Btw, your code works and does what I want.  Any idea why the code that I wrote does not work?

Comment: @user129206: Again, you'll have to create a complete test case that demonstrates the problem. The markup and code you've shown work: http://jsbin.com/ukuvaz

Comment: Thanks for pointing to jsbin.com, better than jsfiddle... And the code that I wrote actually works with different jquery versions on the internet, as low as 1.4.2

Comment: @user129206: Right. That's the point: It works. Your question says it *doesn't* work. For us to help you with that, you have to demonstrate for us what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery provides helper methods for this kind of thing...

```
var premiumtypecodes = arr.map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

See [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [makeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) a jQuery method that `Convert an array-like object into a true JavaScript array.`

```
var obj = $(".producttypeid");

var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
```

Taken from the docs

> Many methods, both in jQuery and in JavaScript in general, return
>   objects that are array-like. For example, the jQuery factory function
>   $() returns a jQuery object that has many of the properties of an
>   array (a length, the [] array access operator, etc.), but is not
>   exactly the same as an array and lacks some of an array's built-in
>   methods (such as .pop() and .reverse()).
>
> Note that after the conversion, any special features the object had
>   (such as the jQuery methods in our example) will no longer be present.
>   The object is now a plain array.

Comment: `arr[i].value` is the original code: this adds the DOM elements rather than their values.

Comment: @lonesomeday i agree with what you are saying but i understood that he wanted to create an array of DOM elements (the question is not that clear)

Comment: I just need to capture the value attribute and make an array. Here is the sample text. <input class="producttypeid" type="hidden" value="512">

Comment: @user129206 then look at the other answers, as they are correct

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it

var arr = [];

$(".producttypeid").each(function(index,selector){

arr.push( $(selector).text() );

});